# How does bootstrap collapse columns at a certain viewport width using only css?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How does bootstrap change from applying col-sm-* to col-xs-* when the viewport width passes some boundary (if width>768, apply sm, else apply xs).

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- NAVIGATION -->
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li><a href="">Manage Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Billing</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Account Settings</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- VIEW -->
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-xs-12">
            VIEW
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In bootstrap.css, I see that if @media(min-width>768) sets col-sm-* width's and float-left, but nowhere do I see that col-xs-* should be ignored.
In particular, I see that if the window is getting bigger, how setting col-sm-* might override col-xs-* (maybe a qwirk of browsers - the last attribute to be applied is the one rendered), but if the window is getting smaller, col-sm-* is never told to not be applied, if that makes sense.

Comment: I'm guessing here, but isn't bootstrap a mobile-first framework? If so, then col-xs-* is sort of like a default value, and everything up from there should either inherit or override its attributes. Does that sort of explain the behaviour you're seeing?

Answer (score 3):

As was pointed out in the comments, Bootstrap is designed to be "mobile first" which means that it is styled first for mobile screens, and then additional styles are added in as the screen gets larger. This is done through the use of CSS media queries, specifically using `min-width` conditions.

These `min-width` media queries add all the styles within them to the page once the browser exceeds that minimum width. Additionally, as you were getting at in your question, CSS does in fact use the last style applied, when the same style is applied more than once (this assumes that both styles have the same selector weighting, but that's a whole separate topic)

With these two things in mind, if you were to inspect those column elements, you would see that when your browser is large, the `col-xs-*` class is getting applied, but is being overridden by the `col-sm-*` class. This is because this class's order in the CSS comes after the other one, giving it priority. However, once your browser's width drops below that point, the media query removes those styles from the page, allowing the `col-xs-*` class to regain it's precedence.

Let me know if you'd like me to explain anything any more in-depth, and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: "once your browser's width drops below that point, the media query removes those styles from the page" - Where can I read this in the spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)?

Comment: With reference to my comment below, is it 'removes' or 're-applies and overrides?'

Comment: To clarify my wording a bit, the styles aren't necessarily "removed" from the page... You can think about it that way, but really they are still there, they just no longer apply to anything. It's sort of the same idea as if you have a style for a specific class name, but don't use that class name anywhere in your document. That style is still there, but it does not apply to any elements.

Answer (score 1):

A few questions or comments in there each worthy of response for one reason or another, so I'll respond individually:

> "if width>768, apply sm, else apply xs"

Actually, this assumption is wrong. It's not ELSE apply xs, but AND apply xs. Since some of sm's attributes override xs's attributes, they win.

> "In bootstrap.css, I see that if @media(min-width>768) sets col-sm-*
>   width's and float-left, but nowhere do I see that col-xs-* should be
>   ignored"

It's not that col-xs-* gets ignored, but that col-sm-* overrides some attributes of col-sm-*, when the right screen width fires the corresponding media query.

> "maybe a qwirk of browsers"

Not a quirk of broswer at all, but a cornerstone feature of CSS, in that the last application of a specific style rule wins (unless overruled by specificity, or !important).

> "but if the window is getting smaller, col-sm-* is never told to not be
>   applied"

Actually, it *is* told not to be applied, by the media query. If your window is at 767px, col-sm-* is not applied at all, because `@media(min-width>768)` excludes it.

Hope some of this helps... Didn't mean to go tit-for-tat on your comments, but if any one of these is the one that helps you understand, best to share them all!

Comment: "Actually, it is told not to be applied, by the media query. If your window is at 767px, col-sm-* is not applied at all, because @media(min-width>768) excludes it." - But by this point col-sm-* have already been applied. But I think I got it now. Everytime the browser re-sizes, it goes through the css again and, as you said, this time the min-width>768 doesn't apply and col-xs-* overrides everything. I'm trying to find in the spec this overriding behavior of css though (in my quest to learn how to read specifications).

Comment: Interesting point. I've never considered what actually *turns off* the col-md-* classes when dropping below the threshold...